# Keep getting mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Tags: php

Working on a log in system, but i keep getting this error

```
//$User = 'kv96';
//$Pass = 'passkv';

//echo isValidLogin($User, $Pass);


function isValidLogin($username, $password) {
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Log_in WHERE Password = '$Pass' AND User_ID ='$User'"); //Finds the database and chooses the row
    //$result = mysqli_query($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //Fetches the row
    if($row['User_ID'] != null && $row['Password'] != null){return true;}
    else{return false;}

function getUsernameRole($username) {
    return "instructor";
}
mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

Can someone explain why this error is popping, i dont see why the query is failing?

Comment: your $Pass and $User are commented out. What are those variables referencing in isValidLogin?

Comment: Where is `$link` defined? Passwords should be hashed. This could be open to SQL injections you should use parameterized queries. As is `$link` is out of scope for `isValidLogin`.

Comment: you commented 

//$result = mysqli_query($query);

therefore there is no such thing as $result

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you commented out your `$result` yet you were using to fetch the database array. You should be using `$query` instead, or get rid of the 2 `//` before your `$result`.

Not only that, you forgot to parse `$link` through the parameters of your function. Therefore the query will not be successful.

Another problem, you used `$pass` and `$user` variables inside of your query, however, you have not passed them through the parameters of your function either. You must change `$username` to `$user` and so on..

I've also changed your while loop to a row count. This will save you from using unnecessary code and is way more practical; saves you doing a while loop and checking if values return null.

```
function isValidLogin($link, $user, $pass) { // parsing through the connection link and $user, $pass variables
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Log_in WHERE Password = '$Pass' AND User_ID ='$User'"); //Finds the database and chooses the row
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A suggestion I would like to make (and HIGHLY recommend) is to use prepared statements to protect against SQL injection, however, you can find many posts on how to do that.

Comment: `$Pass` and `$User` are undefined.

Comment: `$user, $pass` != `$User, $Pass`. You also should explain that the call to this function will need the link as the first parameter.